# Consulta Query 1:N

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Tabela: estoque
id_estoque
nome
```

---

```
Tabela: atributos
id_atributo
id_estoque
nome
```

E por exemplo necessito de saber se existem 2 atributos de nome `X` e o de nome `Y` ligado ao estoque `Z`. E gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer isso sem fazer 2 `INNER JOIN`. Atualmente faço da forma a seguir mas acredito que deva existir alguma forma mais simples que eu não conheça:

```
SELECT e.nome 
FROM estoque e 
INNER JOIN atributos a1 ON e.id_estoque = a1.id_estoque AND a1.nome = 'X'
INNER JOIN atributos a2 ON e.id_estoque = a2.id_estoque AND a2.nome = 'Y'
WHERE e.id_estoque = 'Z'
```

Porque para saber com 2 são apenas e inner join, mas se quisesse saber por 5 teria de fazer 5 joins? Alguém conhece alguma forma mais simples de realizar esse tipo de query? Deve haver os 2 atributos associados ao estoque obrigatoriamente, não adianta ter só `X` ou só `Y` associado, deve haver os 2.

Exemplo de dados:

```
Tabela: estoque
id_estoque|nome
'A'|'A'
'B'|'B'
'C'|'C'
'Z'|'Z'

Tabela: atributos
id_atributo|id_estoque|nome
'X'|'A'|'X'
'Y'|'A'|'Y'
'N'|'A'|'N'
'X'|'Z'|'X'
'Y'|'Z'|'Y'
'M'|'Z'|'M'
```

Comment: Acredito que funcionaria usando `WHERE a.nome like '%X' OR a.nome like '%Y'`

Comment: não serve porque não é para ser or e sim para ter os 2 atributos obrigatóriamente associado ao estoque

Answer (score 2):

Você faz questão que a consulta seja um “e” e não um “ou”? Se sim, o único jeito é fazer um `INNER JOIN` por atributo mesmo.

Se você quiser deixar mais claro que id_estoque é a chave que vincula as duas tabelas, você pode usar `INNER JOIN <tabela> USING (<coluna>, <coluna>, …)`; sua consulta ficaria

```
SELECT e.nome 
FROM estoque e 
     INNER JOIN atributos a1 USING (id_estoque)
     INNER JOIN atributos a2 USING (id_estoque)
WHERE e.id_estoque = 'Z' AND
      a1.nome = 'X' AND
      a2.nome = 'Y'
```

(eu movi as condições sobre o nome da lista para o WHERE, para poder deixar só as chaves no USING)

---

Uma coisa me salta aos olhos: um mesmo atributo se aplica a mais de um estoque? Se sim, o seu *design* tem um problema — na hora que alguém adicionar um atributo mas escrever errado o nome, ele não vai aparecer quando a pessoa procurar de novo pelo atributo escrito certo (ou com acento/sem acento, maiúsculas/minúsculas, …). A solução é usar *três* tabelas:

```
Tabela: estoque
-------
id_estoque
nome

Tabela: atributo
-------
id_atributo
nome

Tabela: atributo_estoque
-------
id_atributo
id_estoque
```

Aí a consulta ficaria algo tipo

```
SELECT e.nome 
FROM estoque e 
     INNER JOIN atributo_estoque a1 USING (id_estoque)
     INNER JOIN atributo_estoque a2 USING (id_estoque)
WHERE e.id_estoque = 'Z' AND
      a1.id_estoque = (SELECT id_estoque FROM atributo WHERE nome = 'X') AND
      a2.id_estoque = (SELECT id_estoque FROM atributo WHERE nome = 'Y')
```

(falando em termos de [normalização de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados), isso coloca as tabelas na [segunda forma normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form))

Comment: No meu banco já são essas 3 tabelas, só usei isso aqui para exemplo. Mas então não existe outra forma sem ser `INNER JOIN`? Pois sim faço questão que seja AND

Comment: Se você estivesse usando um outro sistema de banco de dados que não o MySQL, você poderia fazer a consulta com INTERSECT, cf. [documentação do PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-union.html). Você está preocupado com a performance da consulta?

Comment: Com performance também, mas a quantidade de join com o banco indexado usando chave estrangeira, sei que não é isso que irá piorar a performance da query, porém achei que havia algo mais simples, com desempenho melhor ou igual a esse. Pois me deparo com o problema de as vezes ter que construir 5 INNER JOIN, isso é custo para o php, se houvesse algo mais simples seria melhor.

Comment: Olha a tabela neste [artigo do Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) — o tempo que o MySQL vai precisar pra puxar a sua tabela no disco (8000000 ns) é muito maior que o tempo que o PHP vai levar para concatenar as strings em memória (1000 ms, se o PHP for muito porco); o tempo que o PHP vai levar simplesmente não é mensurável. Se _um dia_ o seu aplicativo tiver o tamanho do Facebook, _aí sim_ você vai precisar pensar nisso (mas aí você vai ter virado pelo menos multi-milionário no processo. :))

Comment: Se não existe outra forma continuarei assim, era mais curiosidade mesmo de que houvesse outra forma, por questão de desempenho já sabia que estava bom.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que funcionaria assim:

```
SELECT e.nome 
FROM estoque e 
INNER JOIN atributos a ON e.id_estoque = a.id_estoque
WHERE e.id_estoque = 'Z' AND a.nome like '%X' AND a.nome like '%Y'
```

Comment: não serve porque não é para ser or e sim para ter os 2 atributos obrigatóriamente associado ao estoque

Comment: Poste alguns exemplos de dados que possuiria nas duas tabelas e um exemplo que satisfaria a sua necessidade, essa lógica está meio confusa

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta o exemplos

Comment: Certo, agora no seu `select` qual seria um exemplo de retorno válido?

Comment: Retornar apenas, o nome do estoque que satisfaz a regra, no caso o  `Z`, porque a necessidade é saber se existe ou não um registro no banco que satisfaz essa regra.

Comment: Ou seja, no seu exemplo ele retornaria os registros 'X' 'Y' e 'Z' da tabela de atributos, correto?

Comment: `a.nome like '%X' AND a.nome like '%Y'` é uma contradição; essa consulta nunca vai retornar nenhuma linha.